# DAML bug when following the tutorial

Tags: daml

I followed the DAML tutorial, and it seems that there is a bug:

https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/quickstart.html#try-out-the-application

> Try creating a contract from a template. Issue an Iou to yourself by
>   clicking on the Iou:Iou row, filling it out as shown below and
>   clicking Submit.
>   http://localhost:4000/templates/Iou:Iou@f7592b50015725110188fe00bea8373fdcdceaeea90a1664682df422a9853b6e/

After filling out the form and clicking Submit, I get this error:

> Error: Network error: Network request failed with status 500 -
>   "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Which version of the DAML SDK are you using? Do you see any errors being logged in the sandbox.log file?

Comment: I've moved this question to https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/issues/5324

Comment: I tried again and it worked fine. I don't manage to reproduce the problem, so I close the ticket.